# Amazon SQS: Get the Number of Consumers Listening on the Queue

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jms, message-queue, amazon-sqs

I know that for ActiveMQ we can use JMX to retrieve information about connections to the queue.

For Amazon SQS, how do we get the number of concurrent consumers listening on the queue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no built-in method to determine who is consuming or how many consumers there are listening for SQS messages.

You will have to create your own method.

You could use CloudWatch to post metrics about listeners listening to your SQS queue(s). Once you have the metrics, you would use those metrics to determine the number of consumers there are.

Comment: There are no metrics for SQS to get number of consumers in Cloudwatch

Comment: @TarunKundhiya Correct. You must post your own metrics to CloudWatch.